# Fill Joined Objects when Fill Command does not work

Tags: vertices, faces

Been playing with Blender mainly for 3d Printing and object creation.  I have looked at quite a few Youtube videos and things have been a learning process.  I want to say thank you to the Blender community for all your help.

I have two objects that have been joined (shown below).  I would like to fill the void from top to bottom but leave the gap shown in the center.  If I could duplicate the object and mirror that down that may work, but would be an unnecessary complex object.

I have tried to leverage the fill command to completely fill the void from top to bottom even ensuring the mesh is being selected via the Alt-Click to highlight.  I keep getting and error that says "No Faces Filled".  I have also tried to extrude the faces from the top or bottom section and join them up in the middle to no success.

Ideally I would like two close off the front section so it looks like a solid face in the front.  Not sure if there is a way to pull down the faces and match the curve/angle. When done, it should resemble a face mack someone would wear

[image]

What the outcome would look like if the front section was filled.  I simply put a Sphere in to represent what I was looking for.

[image]

Comment: You'll have to be clearer on what you mean.
What do you mean by "fill the void from top to bottom"? What void?
The fill operation closes holes in the mesh, your mesh doesn't seem to have any holes (at least that we can see in the screenshot).

Comment: Where the object has the U-shape, I would like to fill the entire U-shape so that it is a solid object while maintaining the U When it is filled.  In essence, join the grey top section to the grey bottom section in an arc (if possible.

Comment: You have to first delete the faces of the side you want to connect on each U, then you can use LoopTools > bridge (might need to enable looptools addon in preferences window) to bridge the edges between both 'U's. The bridge operation has lots of options to make arcs and things like that

Comment: So your recommendation would be to remove the faces from either the top or bottom object and then try to bridge to the now open faced area?  I will give that a try.  Thank you for the direction

Comment: Yes, you'd need to remove the top faces of the bottom U, and the bottom faces of the top U, so that there will be no faces inside the mesh when you bridge between them. 
(faces inside the mesh will cause issues, especially if you intend on 3D printing the object)

Comment: Awesome, I will give that a try.  I may play some with bridging to see if that gives me more confidence.  I did upload an additional image showing something like what I was desiring but placing a sphere as shown would fill in the open part of the U-shape.